# Nutritional value of hops?

Tags: health, hops

Since beers are made with hops, what nutritional value do those hop give to a human body when beer is consumed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None, the hops are added to provide a bitter flavour and because they have an antibiotic property that favours yeast over other microorganisms.

The hops are filtered out in the brewing process so there is no calorific gain.

In a typical UK beer recipe the hops are typically 1% of the dry ingredients.

Comment: Do you have any scientific references?

Comment: I don't have any literature on it I just asked a friend with a degree in brewing.